ping and getent hosts give different result
I have entry in /etc/hosts
1.1.1.1  db_external
When I am doing ping I get it correct
ping db_external
PING db_external (1.1.1.1)

When I am doing
getent hosts db_external 

for some reason I got :
::1             db_external.localhost

What can be reason in that?
cat /etc/nsswitch.conf|grep hosts
#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files dns myhostname

Vult cloud image of centos 7
ps getent ahostsv4 or getent ahosts  - works. But I have many entries in software with getent hosts

Try getent hosts db_external. (ending with dot). Also, do you have an environment variable named HOSTALIASES? See the "Description" section of gethostbyname(3) which is called by getent to do the request.

Like harrymc says, getent hosts uses gethostbyname, which looks for ipv6 first and if found, returns that. Which is what happens for you. ahosts works because it uses getaddrinfo rather than gethostbyname.

ipv6 is off. Why it is checking ipv6? and why it FOUND?

with dot at end it return zero(no even lines). No  HOSTALIASES.
